# Proving vector subspace is closed on multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

I'm trying to prove if F1 is a subspace for R^4. I've already proved that the 0 vector is in F1 and also F1 is closed under addition. I'm confused on how to be able to prove it is closed under multiplication?

I have:

Take some scalar of alpha. alpha * F1 = (alpha*x, alpha*y, alpha*z, alpha*t) = alpha*3x + alpha*2y + alpha*z = -alpha*t. But what do I do from here?

Comment: Instead of including a screenshot (not recommended) with lots of extraneous information, you could improve the question by simply typing the definition of $F_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be easier to understand if you took some $(x, y, z, t) \in \mathcal{F}_1$ and checked whether $\alpha (x, y, z, t) = (\alpha x, \alpha y, \alpha z, \alpha t)$ also belongs to $\mathcal{F}_1$.

Comment: So if I say let alpha = 3, then it would be like: 3(x,y,z,t) = (3x,3y,3z,3t) --> 9x+6y+3z=-3t. And since I proved that (1,1,1,-6) is in F1 when I proved its closed under addition, we apply the same vector and see 18=18? Wouldn't this just always be true.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{F}_1 = \{ (x, y, z, t) \in \mathbf{R}^4 : 3 x + 2 y + z + t = 0 \}$.

**S1**) $\mathbf{0} \in \mathcal{F}_1$.

This holds obviously.

**S2**) $\mathcal{F}_1 $ is closed under vector addition.

Suppose $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2 \in \mathcal{F}_1$.

Then we take

$$
\mathbf{v}_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1, t_1), \ \
\mathbf{v}_2 = (x_2, y_2, z_2, t_2).
$$

Then they satisfy
$$
3 x_1 + 2 y_1 + z_1 + t_1 = 0, \ \ 
3 x_2 + 2 y_2 + z_2 + t_2 = 0 \tag{1}
$$

Adding the two equations in (1), we get
$$
3 (x_1 + x_2) + 2 (y_1 + y_2) + (z_1 + z_2) + (t_1 + t_2) = 0.
$$

Thus,
$$
\mathbf{v}_1 + \mathbf{v}_2 \in \mathcal{F}_1
$$

Hence, S1) has been proved.

S2) $\mathcal{F}_1$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Let $\alpha \in \mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{v} \in \mathcal{F}_1$.

We take $\mathbf{v} = (x, y, z, t)$. Then
$$
3 x + 2 y + z + t = 0 \tag{2}
$$

Multiplying both sides of (2) by $\alpha$, we get
$$
3 (\alpha x) + 2 (\alpha y) + (\alpha z) + (\alpha t) = 0
$$

This shows that $\alpha \mathbf{v} \in \mathcal{F}_1$.

Hence, S3) has been proved.

Hence, $\mathcal{F}_1$ is a subspace of $\mathbf{R}^4$. $ \ \ \ \ \blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain the S3 part --> why does 3(ax) + 2(ay) + (az) + (at) = 0 mean av is in F1? So I can apply it to other problems

Comment: By definition, $\mathcal{F}_1$ consists of all 4-D vectors of the form $\mathbf{v} = (x, y, z, t)$ which satisfies $3 x + 2 y + z + t = 0$. We showed that $(a x, a y, a z, a t) \in \mathcal{F}_1$. In other words, $a \mathbf{v} \in \mathcal{F}_1$.